# Failed to copy inputStream into File

Tags: java, file, nio

I'm using this code to write from an inputStream to File. It creates the directory, but the uploaded files are empty (with no contents in it). How can I handle this?

```
 try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
                    Path filePath = this.rootLocation.resolve(filename);
                    File targetFile = new File(String.valueOf(filePath));    
                    Files.copy(inputStream, targetFile.toPath());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I catch contents of the file like

```
String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                    .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

So I'm pretty sure that the issue is in

```
Files.copy(inputStream, targetFile.toPath());
```

Comment: Which type is ``file`` in the very first line?

Comment: Do you "catch" the contents of the file before calling Files.copy? Once you read (consume) the InputStream you cannot read it again. That would explain why the file is empty...

Comment: @Matt It's MultiPartFile

Comment: I've copy-pasted the code into my IDE and it works fine, having replaced  the ``MultiPartFile`` by ``File``. Is there possibly a hidden/obscured exception?